# css selectors not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<dl>
  <dt>A</dt>
  <dd>B</dd>
  <dt>C</dt>
  <dd>D</dd>
  <dt>E</dt>
  <dd>F</dd>
</dl>
```

and the following CSS

```
dt,
dd {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

dt:last-child,
dd:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

The problem is that the last `dt` has a border.

What is wrong? What am I missing?

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxf8v8mg/).

Comment: That is because the last `<dt>` is not the last child. The `<dd>` it taken as the last child of your list

Comment: So actually, the CSS *is* working as expected ;).

Comment: It was working properly but not how I expected. Now I understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `dt` element isn't the last child, the last `dd` element is. A parent object can only have one last-child, so you should use [`last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) instead:

```css
dt,
dd {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
    
dt:last-of-type,
dd:last-of-type {
   border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>A</dt>
  <dd>B</dd>
  <dt>C</dt>
  <dd>D</dd>
  <dt>E</dt>
  <dd>F</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to target `dt:last-of-type` since the last `dt` is not the `last-child` of its parent (it is in fact followed by another `dd` element)

> Example: https://jsfiddle.net/bxf8v8mg/2/

---

As a side note you could optimize your code like so

```
dt:not(:last-of-type),
dd:not(:last-child) {
     border-bottom:  1px solid #000;
}
```

So you don't need to reset the border with a specific rule later.

> Example (optimized): https://jsfiddle.net/bxf8v8mg/5/

Answer (score 1):

Here `dt` is not the last child `dd` is the last child of `dl`

Use

```
dt:last-of-type { border-bottom: none; }
```

The :last-of-type selector matches every element that is the last child, of a particular type, of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 dt:nth-last-of-type(1), dd:nth-last-of-type(1){
     border-bottom: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write `dd:nth-last-child(2)` so you target the second-last child of the parent that is `dl`. Or you can simply write `dd:last-of-type` to target the last  `dd`